# What input forms are 'reasonable'?

Tags: discussion, formatting

It's very common for a question to leave the input format unspecified and simply let the golfer choose a 'reasonable' input format. I'd say this is a bit vague, and we should decide what can be considered reasonable.

I recognize two separate categories, with subcategories (feel free to edit):

- **Input separation.**
- **Input data.**

  - Strings.
  - Numbers.
  - Images.

In order to organize this, post your suggested input method, **one per answer**, in the following format:

---

> ### Category (- Subcategory) - Name
>
> This is a short description of the input method. However absurd it might be, leave your own opinion for the comments.

<sup>-1 from me, this is just absurd. — [orlp](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/4162/orlp) 3 hours ago</sup>

---

Then, any input method with a negative score is by default *disallowed*. Any input method with a positive score is by default *allowed*. Any input method not listed may or may not be reasonable, and should be confirmed by the challenge poster, and possibly added to the list.

Comment: The input source [has been discussed before](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2447/8478). [It's also strongly discouraged](http://meta.computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/85/tag-name-pixel-shader-or-fragment-shader#comment132_85) to post options that aren't your own opinion for polling purposes.

Comment: @MartinBüttner I think that's not the same as what's happening here however. Each answer is a poll of itself, rather than an option to a poll. I'll remove input source from this discussion.

Answer (score 1):

### Input data - Numbers - Scientific notation

Reading a number encoded in scientific notation. E.g.: `2.321e21`.

Answer (score 0):

### Input separation - Newlines

Separating input by placing newlines in between them.

Answer (score 0):

### Input separation - Any combination of reasonable separations.

Separating input by using any combination of other reasonable separations. For example, using both newlines and spaces:

```
3 "test"
5 "cool"
```